# Firebase Database - Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (19.3.0)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-crash-reporting

I met this issue in my project and have no idea to fix it. Help me please.

My project has implemented firebase data before (11.8.0) and run normally. I recently add firebase crashlytics sdk (database update to 19.3.0) and get crash when running project with release mode (minifyEnable = true).

My gradle file

```
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.1")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.7")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0")
```

My code

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        DatabaseReference dbRef = database.getReference("/mydbkey");
        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               // Do my stuff
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Do my stuff
            }
        });
```

The crashed message:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (19.3.0). If you are not already on the latest version of the Firebase SDKs, try updating your dependencies. Should this problem persist, please file a report at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk
       at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform$1$1.run(AndroidPlatform.java:96)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method object()Lcom/***/android/am4; in class Lcom/***/android/am4; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.***.android.am4' appears in /data/app/com.***.debug-fG3zQ87gx1RUrYnvZ7rj7g==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
       at com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper.serializeJsonValue(JsonMapper.java:69)
       at com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper.serializeJsonValue(JsonMapper.java:58)
       at com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper.serializeJson(JsonMapper.java:38)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.send(WebsocketConnection.java:231)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.sendData(Connection.java:243)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.sendRequest(Connection.java:117)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.sendSensitive(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:1177)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.sendAction(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:1164)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.sendStats(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:1116)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.sendConnectStats(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:1159)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.onReady(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:310)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.onConnectionReady(Connection.java:217)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.onHandshake(Connection.java:210)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.onControlMessage(Connection.java:182)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.onMessage(Connection.java:132)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.appendFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:256)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:303)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.access$000(WebsocketConnection.java:34)
       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection$WSClientTubesock$2.run(WebsocketConnection.java:86)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: I am seeing the same crash logs in my app. Did you find any resolution to this?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, add this into proguard rules

-keep class org.json.* { *; }

Answer (score 1):

I hope you know **minifyEnabled true** why we use it and what it will do in our app, You need to change and add some sniped code in your project.

Put **@Keep** at the top of your data class what you are using to receive data from firebase.

Add mentioned below the line in your Proguard file

> -keep class org.json.* { *; }

It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

So I had an app that was working fine untill i dont know what i did.
any ways after looking for a solution for some time. I got the fix.

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.0.0'

Just downgrade the Firebase Database to 19.0.0

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing this problem.

After changing `minifyEnabled` to `false`, it's working fine.

Comment: Where should this be set?

Comment: on your App level build gradle.

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy but by setting minifyEnable to false, that mean I do not use proguard in my project and in fact, I am in need of it

Comment: after the long search i found most commonly used answer.Try this, if you implement this **disable** it.             `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`

Comment: Setting minifyEnabled to false makes you app prone to hacking. This advice is really bad